# how to solve json data for loop

Tags: javascript

```
for (var key in data) {
     $(".chat").html('<li class="\ left clearfix message \"></li>');
     $(".message").html(data[key].message);
}
```

response data

```
[{"id":1,"message":"message 3","taker_id":"124","giver_id":"102","status":"0","stamp":"2016-08-24"},
```

{"id":5,"message":"message 2","taker_id":"124","giver_id":"102","status":"0","stamp":"2016-08-17"},{"id"
:6,"message":"This is the new message test service now we are ok","taker_id":"124","giver_id":"102","status"
:"0","stamp":"2016-08-11"}]

Output

```
<li class=" left clearfix message ">This is the new message test service now we are ok</li>
```

Problem :
html

not generated separately

Please Help !

Comment: because you keep overriding the element's text on every iteration. What do you actually want to see? If you want multiple elements, you should be appending.

Comment: <li class=" left clearfix message ">message 3</li>
<li class=" left clearfix message ">message 2</li>
<li class=" left clearfix message ">This is the new message test service now we are ok</li>
I want Please Help !

Comment: May be Problem from for loop , I dont Understand , I want message separately with html li , with message

Comment: So did you look at my answer below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With html() you are just replacing the content on every iteration. You need to append

```js
var resp = [{
  "id": 1,
  "message": "message 3",
  "taker_id": "124",
  "giver_id": "102",
  "status": "0",
  "stamp": "2016-08-24"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "message": "message 2",
  "taker_id": "124",
  "giver_id": "102",
  "status": "0",
  "stamp": "2016-08-17"
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "message": "This is the new message test service now we are ok",
  "taker_id": "124",
  "giver_id": "102",
  "status": "0",
  "stamp": "2016-08-11"
}]


resp.forEach(function(obj) {
  $(".chat").append('<li class="left clearfix message ">' + obj.message + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chat"></ul>
```

If you really do not want to have the text in the string, than you would need to do something like this:

```
resp.forEach(function(obj) {
  var li = $('<li class="left clearfix message "></li>');
  li.text(obj.message);
  $(".chat").append(li);
});
```